# How can I separate an array into different rows in a matrix (Matlab)

Tags: matlab

I am trying to construct a NaN matrix that has parts of an array as its rows using For Loops (or really any form that works)

For example:

```
W = [0 0 0 2 3 2 0 0 4 5 6 6 5 0 0 0 0 8 8 9 8 0 0 0 0 ... ]
```

whenever there is a brake caused by the zeros I want to iterate only the numbers and not the zeros in such that whenever there are numbers again separated by zeroes it forms a new row each time in my new matrix, resulting in:

```
Matrix = NaN(5) %just big enough to fit everything
Matrix =  [2 3 2 NaN NaN; 4 5 6 6 5;8 8 9 8 NaN] % and so forth
```

*I've been using a Nested For Loop for this but still getting errors.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: What about `W = [... 0 0 4 5 6 6 5 7 0 0 0 0 8 8 ... ]`? Here, you have six consecutive numbers. In the result, is the width of `5` fixed, i.e. one would get `[...; 4 5 6 6 5; 7 NaN NaN NaN NaN; ...]`? By now, the problem statement seems not be complete.

Comment: What about `[0 1 0 2 3 4 5 6 0]`? Can you guarantee that each row can be divisible by `5`, or some other fixed number? Are all numbers guaranteed to be positive?

Comment: Sorry, yes its not fixed to 5 in fact I used that to give an idea but really as long as I can get something looking like the final matrix it works for me. The six consecutive number turned to a 5 is a typo I apologize for that

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution without using loops.

```
W = [0 0 0 2 3 2 0 0 4 5 6 6 5 0 0 0 0 8 8 9 8 0 0 0 0];
W_idx = logical(W);
lbl = cumsum([diff([false W_idx]) > 0]) .* W_idx;
%lbl = bwlabel(W_idx) %use the image processing toolbox
count = accumarray(lbl(:)+1,1).';
count = count(2:end);
result_idx = (1:max(count)).' <= count ;
result = NaN(size(result_idx));
result(result_idx) = W(W_idx);
result = result.';
```

And the result:

```
result =

     2     3     2   NaN   NaN
     4     5     6     6     5
     8     8     9     8   NaN
```

If you need indices of numbers you can create a separate array for the time indices:

```
time_data = 1:25;
time_result = NaN(size(result_idx));
time_result(result_idx) = time_data(W_idx);
time_result = time_result.';
```

Comment: Thank you. In case I have multiple Ws, how can I make this into a loop so that itll run into multiple Ws and solved them the same way?

Comment: What if my W has two rows now such that W = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25; 0 0 0 2 3 2 0 0 4 5 6 6 5 0 0 0 0 8 8 9 8 0 0 0 0] The first row being the time constant how can I tell at what time the first row of the new matrix extended across the first row of W? Such that I will know from 2 3 3 it was time 4 5 6; and 4 5 6 6 5 it was time 9 10 11 12 13 and so forth? Maybe this could be placed in another whole new NaN matrix of its own?

Comment: For the first comment you can place the code in a [function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/function.html) and call it for each W.

Comment: For the second comment please edit your question extending it with what are you describing. It is simple. I will assume that you have an array W and an array 'time'. If 'time' contains sequential natural numbers there is no need to create time array

Comment: @Kanade Answer updated.